# Visual Studio 2017 debugger eats first keystroke after exception

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I recently upgraded from VS2015 to VS2017.

In 2015, while debugging (after an exception), if you start typing, it will put what you type down... as normal.

In 2017, I get an exception, I scroll halfway up the class, then type a key...

... and it scrolls back down to where the run-cursor is and ignores my keystroke, instead going into a sort of 'edit mode' or something. Likewise, If I get an exception and try to add ".ToList()", it instead adds just "ToList()", since the first character isn't input (scrolling back up to where my cursor actually is in doing so - this is disorienting).

How can I get rid of this behaviour, and make VS2017 automatically go into "edit mode" on exception break?

I'm working in a C# solution and my VS version is 15.8.2.

Comment: Hi, could you reproduce it with a simple demo? If yes, you can share it to us by onedrive and add some reproduce steps, so that we could reproduce it. It seems I could not reproduce this issue on my side.

Comment: @Alex Just creating a console application and throwing an Exception in main will produce the error for me.